# More Pythonic way to define custom __eq__ method using try, assert, except

Tags: python

<strike>The code below works</strike>(EDIT: actually, turns out it doesn't!), but I don't like the hanging `return True` statement that appears after the `try: except:` block.

```
class MySlottedClass(object):
    def __new__(klass, **slots):
        klass.__slots__ = []
        for k in slots:
            klass.__slots__.append(k)
        return super(MySlottedClass,klass).__new__(klass)
    def __init__(self, **slots):
        for k,v in slots.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
        super(MySlottedClass,self).__new__()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        for slot in self.__slots__:
            try:
                assert getattr(self, slot) == getattr(other,slot), "Not Equal"
            except (AssertionError, AttributeError):
                return False
        return True

##Testing
##Note that the above class definition is just a skeleton
##The below objects are created using 4 different but identically defined classes
##In the actual problem, I am using a metaclass to make these classes dynamically
msc1 = MySlottedClassABC(a=1,b=1,c=3)
msc2 = MySlottedClassAB(a=1,b=1)
msc3 = MySlottedClassBA(b=2,a=1)
msc4 = MySlottedClassXY(x=1,y=2)

assert msc1!=msc2
assert msc2==msc3
assert msc3==msc2
assert msc2!=msc4
```

Is there a more pythonic way of writing the `__eq__` method for this class?

Comment: with your code `MySlottedClass(a=1,b=2) == MySlottedClass(a=1,b=2,c=3)` is TRUE ... is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to recreate a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Using `namedtuple` will allow to create classes on the dynamically, test for equality and other interesting things. The downside is that since tuples are immutable, so to are namedtuples and you will have to create a new object instead of updating an attribute. namedtuples will not check the order of your slots, so you must order your slots lexicographically or add your own `__eq__` method that accounts for slot order.

Example usage:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MySlottedClassAB = namedtuple("MySlottedClassAB", ['a', 'b'])
MySlottedClassABC = namedtuple("MySlottedClassABC", ['a', 'b', 'c'])

class MySlottedClassBA(namedtuple("MySlottedClassBA", ['b', 'a'])):
    def addAB(self):
        return self.a + self.b

msc1 = MySlottedClassAB(a=1, b=2)
msc2 = MySlottedClassBA(b=2, a=1)
msc3 = MySlottedClassABC(1, 2, 3)

print(msc1)
print(msc2)
print(msc3)
print("{} == {} is {}".format(msc1, msc1, msc1==msc1))
print("{} == {} is {}".format(msc1, msc2, msc1==msc2))
print("{} == {} is {}".format(msc1, msc3, msc1==msc3))
print("msc2.addAB() is {}".format(msc2.addAB()))
```

If the order of your slots and mutability are important the following will work (for python 2).

```
class MySlottedClassMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MySlottedClassMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs):
        assert "__slots__" in attrs
        attrs["_ordered_slots"] = tuple(sorted(attrs["__slots__"]))

        attrs["__init__"] = create_init(attrs["__slots__"])
        attrs["__eq__"] = create_eq()
        attrs["__str__"] = create_str()

        cls = super(MySlottedClassMeta, metacls).__new__(metacls, name, bases, attrs)
        return cls  

def create_init(slots):
    args = ", ".join(slots)
    assignments = "\n    ".join("self.{0} = {0}".format(attr) for attr in slots)
    init_source = """
def __init__(self, {}):
    {}
""".format(args, assignments)
    exec(init_source, globals(), None)
    return __init__

def create_eq():
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            same_slots = self._ordered_slots == other._ordered_slots
        except AttributeError:
            return False
        if not same_slots:
            return False
        return all(getattr(self, attr) == getattr(other, attr) 
                for attr in self._ordered_slots)
    return __eq__

def create_str():
    def __str__(self):
        attr_values = ", ".join("{}={}".format(s, getattr(self, s)) for s in self.__slots__)
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, attr_values)
    return __str__

class MySlottedClassXY(object):
    __slots__ = ['x', 'y']
    __metaclass__ = MySlottedClassMeta

class MySlottedClassYX(object):
    __slots__ = ['y', 'x']
    __metaclass__ = MySlottedClassMeta

xy1 = MySlottedClassXY(x=1,y=2)
xy2 = MySlottedClassXY(1, 2)
yx = MySlottedClassYX(x=1, y=2)
print(xy1.__slots__)
print(yx.__slots__)
assert xy1 == xy1
assert xy1 == xy2
assert xy1 == yx
```

It's work noting that `__slots__` are overkill in almost all circumstances. Guido Van Rossum stated that they were a premature optimisation based on unfounded fears about the performance of attribute lookups in new style classes. Guido does also state that `__slots__` can reduce the memory footprint of program when you need to create **lots** of small objects.

> I feared that all of the changes in the [new] class system were going to have a negative impact on performance. ... Thus the use of `__slots__` was a way to optimize the lookup of data attributes—a fallback, if you will, in case people were disappointed with the performance impact of the new class system. This turned out unnecessary, but by that time it was of course too late to remove `__slots__`.

http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html

Comment: This answers the question and goes way above and beyond. I think it's a superior solution to comparing the `__dict__` of two of these slotted objects because the class instances do not contain a dict when generated using `___slots__ = '<some slots>'` in the class definition. Thanks for going to to effort of writing a metaclass that does the job of providing mutability (which is the reason I can't use namedtuple). I had already written my own metaclass but I'll be comparing yours to mine to see where it can be improved.

Comment: And I'll add: the readability of the eq descriptor meets the qualification of being "pythonic" quite nicely.

Comment: But see this answer to another of my questions for another (easier?) way to do this without metaclass: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69096/defining-metaclass-instance-methods-inside-of-the-metaclass-factory-instead-of-t/69293#69293

Comment: It's a nice answer, but it's really just a metaclass by another name -- a function that controls class creation.  The advantage of a metaclass is that you can explicitly declare your classes -- it's obvious you are creating a class rather than calling a function. You also only mention "thousands" of instances. That's not a lot. Maybe when you have millions of instances it might be worth using `__slots__`. I would encourage you to examine your init method. It currently is buggy in that it allows an attribute not to be initialised -- `Point()` would be valid.

Comment: You also appear to be using python3 on codereview. Metaclasses are even better in python 3 as you can pass arguments to the metaclass constructor. eg. `class ChildClass(BaseClass, metaclass=YourMetaClass, your_arg="blah"):`

Comment: Yes I am using Python 3. I realize that sublclassing `object` isn't necessary in Python 3 but it's how I learned.

Answer (score 7):

The `return True` is fine.  I think the bigger problem is using an `assert` for flow control.  Asserts do not run at all if the user passes `-O` to `python` on the command line.  You should write something more like this:

```
for slot in self.__slots__:
    if not hasattr(other, slot) or getattr(self, slot) != getattr(other,slot):
        return False
return True
```

Also, `__slots__` needs to be defined at the class level to work, not inside `__init__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If you have a variable number of items, you probably should not be using `__slots__` at all.

Comment: This doesn't quite do what the OP's does, because the OP's handles the case where `other` doesn't have a given `slot`.

Comment: You could use `all()` as well here; `return all(getattr(self, s, object()) == getattr(other, s, object()) for s in self.__slots__)`.

Comment: I do not have a variable number of items for the classes in question. This is just a dumbed down version of what I'm up to using a metaclass to dynamically generate a bunch of slotted classes; see here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69096/defining-metaclass-instance-methods-inside-of-the-metaclass-factory-instead-of-t

Comment: The above is not working for this situation: `msc1 = MySlottedClass(a=1, b=2, c=3)`, `msc2 = MySlottedClass(a=1, b=2)`, `assert msc1 != msc2`, `assert msc2 != msc1`; both assertions produce an `AssertionError`. I think the reason is that the second half of the `if` statement will produce an error when the first half is `False`.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Ugh, nevermind I figured it out. It was pretty obvious:</strike>

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            for slot in self.__slots__:
                assert getattr(self, slot) == getattr(other,slot), "Not Equal"
        except (AssertionError, AttributeError):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

<strike>I should probably close this question so I don't look too dumb.</strike>

---

**Edit:** Nope, no good!

Thanks to everyone's help I now understand there are lots of problems with this way of doing it. First of all, I should not be using `assert` for this since it is mainly for testing, and can be turned off. Second of all, the code doesn't give the expected result for `MySlottedClass(a=1,b=2)==MySlottedClass(a=1,b=2,c=3)`.

I came up with this way instead. Note that the class definition is repeated 4 times so I can test comparison of objects of different classes below; all of the classes are identical, however, until their instances are created. Also note that in the actual use case, I am using a metaclass to generate these classes automatically (and `__eq__` is defined as a part of that metaclass).

```
class MySlottedClassAB(object):
    def __new__(klass, **slots):
        klass.__slots__ = []
        for k in slots:
            klass.__slots__.append(k)
        return super(MySlottedClassAB,klass).__new__(klass)
    def __init__(self, **slots):
        for k,v in slots.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
        super(MySlottedClassAB,self).__init__()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if set(self.__slots__) != set(other.__slots__): return False
        for slot in self.__slots__:
            if getattr(self, slot) != getattr(other,slot):
                return False
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class MySlottedClassBA(object):
    def __new__(klass, **slots):
        klass.__slots__ = []
        for k in slots:
            klass.__slots__.append(k)
        return super(MySlottedClassBA,klass).__new__(klass)
    def __init__(self, **slots):
        for k,v in slots.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
        super(MySlottedClassBA,self).__init__()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if set(self.__slots__) != set(other.__slots__): return False
        for slot in self.__slots__:
            if getattr(self, slot) != getattr(other,slot):
                return False
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class MySlottedClassXY(object):
    def __new__(klass, **slots):
        klass.__slots__ = []
        for k in slots:
            klass.__slots__.append(k)
        return super(MySlottedClassXY,klass).__new__(klass)
    def __init__(self, **slots):
        for k,v in slots.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
        super(MySlottedClassXY,self).__init__()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if set(self.__slots__) != set(other.__slots__): return False
        for slot in self.__slots__:
            if getattr(self, slot) != getattr(other,slot):
                return False
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class MySlottedClassABC(object):
    def __new__(klass, **slots):
        klass.__slots__ = []
        for k in slots:
            klass.__slots__.append(k)
        return super(MySlottedClassABC,klass).__new__(klass)
    def __init__(self, **slots):
        for k,v in slots.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
        super(MySlottedClassABC,self).__init__()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if set(self.__slots__) != set(other.__slots__): return False
        for slot in self.__slots__:
            if getattr(self, slot) != getattr(other,slot):
                return False
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other
```

And here are the testing procedures:

```
##Testing
msc1 = MySlottedClassABC(a=1, b=2, c=3)
msc2 = MySlottedClassAB(a=1, b=2)
msc3 = MySlottedClassBA(b=2, a=1)
msc4 = MySlottedClassXY(x=1, y=2)


assert msc1 != msc2
assert msc2 != msc1
assert msc2 == msc3
assert msc3 == msc2
assert msc3 != msc4
assert msc4 != msc3
```

However, after testing [Joran Beasley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789825/more-pythonic-way-to-define-custom-eq-method-using-try-assert-except/26790039#26790039), I discovered to my surprised it produces IDENTICAL results to that above, with much shorter and more sensible code. So it seems the best way to accomplish this is to simply compare the two `__dict__` attributes.

Comment: **Thanks for sharing your knowledge in a true Q&A style!** Please don't delete your question or answer. See: [Help center: Self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: And you don't look dumb at all to me! There are no dumb questions

Comment: I agree with @Barranka that you should not delete your question or your answer. However, I also strongly agree with Kevin that you should not have code that *depends* on `assert`. If replacing `assert` with `pass` breaks your code, chances are very high that you're not using `assert` properly.

Comment: Yes I was not aware of the nature of `assert` and that it can be turned off. I'm glad I asked about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
def __eq__(self,other):
    return self.__dict__== other.__dict__
```

should work

Comment: try it ;P ... `x = MySlottedClass(a=1,b=2); print x.__dict__`

Comment: This also isn't quite the same as the OP's.  Say there's a key in `other.__dict__` which isn't in `self.__slots__`, but everything else agrees.  Then the OP's code will return True, but this will return False.

Comment: ahh thanks dsm ... meh `se la vie` I expect this is more what he wanted anyway ... even if its not quite the same as what his code does

Comment: @DSM there now he clarified that that behavior was unintentional :P (see OP comments)

Comment: `msc1 = MySlottedClass(a=1, b=2, c=3)`, `msc2 = MySlottedClass(a=1, b=2)`, `assert msc1 != msc2`, `assert msc2 != msc1`; both assertions produce an AssertionError.

Comment: with this? isnt that the behaviour you want?

Comment: Actually I'm uncertain. I don't expect to be comparing classes with mismatched slots in actual practice, so maybe it should produce an error. But then again, maybe it makes more sense to be able to compare all objects of any classes created by my metaclass (which is where `__eq__` is actually defined). I'm not sure which behavior makes more sense.

Comment: If it was me I would just return false ... (as demonstrated by my suggested solution)

Comment: Decided that returning false is the way to go.

Comment: @Rick: If you're defining `__eq__` in a metaclass, it will only be consulted when comparing two *class objects* created from that metaclass.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Actually you can define it inside the metaclass so that two class *instances* are compared. Like this: `class MyMeta(type):`, `def __init__(klass):`, `klass.__eq__ = MyMeta.instance__eq__`, `<other init stuff here>`. Then further down: `@staticmethod`, `def instance__eq__(self, other):`, `<eq defined here>`.

Comment: I've been warned several times by people not to use metaclasses. But I really don't understand why- they are awesome. For those that think metaclasses are deep-black-magic-hard to understand, they really aren't that bad. See here: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html